# Beer's Law: Are the graphs of concentration/time and absorbance/time supposed to look very similar?

Tags: concentration

For my lab, I'm trying to figure out if the reaction between NaOH and crystal violet is a zeroth, first, or second reaction. My slope is 5.714*10^4 and y-intercept 0.008016. In logger pro, after finishing collecting my absorbance/time of NaOH and crystal violet, I tried getting the concentration of crystal violet by using that equation. When graphed, it looks exactly the same as my original graph, just on different numbers. I'm confused by this because when I've tried graphing ln(concentration) and 1/concentration, the graph returned no straight lines. I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Well, since Beer's Law says

$A = \epsilon⋅l⋅c$

And $A$ hence is *directly proportional* to $c$, as Beer's Law actually represents a line equation.

Comment: This is why you do so to get reaction order